# You can't win without clues

Tags: riddle, rhyme

In year 2008 some people got interested in that story, can you tell me exactly what it is about ?

> 1974, something happened on day 228,
>     An animal is holding, full of hate,
>     A wooden device on which we can read,
>     *The cetacean doesn't keep an air of mystery about itself, indeed.*
>     In one solid tint i appear, for sure, 
>     So do my name
>     I am not Walter
>     We are not the same
>     At night, I hope,
>     No need to know Gallileo,
>     To enjoy the show,
>     Just look in the scope

hint1:

> Rupert Morrish found a band in the first stanza, you should try to see if this lead to something (a *wooden device* for example ...)

hint2:

> post title gives you an hint on what represents the whole riddle

hint3:

> For each stanza, you have to find a word. I hope you could then find what this is all about

hint4:

> the whole thing the riddle describes exists since 1949 but 2008 is the year that fits the best each stanza

it has been a long time without a guess, here's another hint:

> object/character/place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh boy, the answer, as hint 2 writes

> is in the title of the puzzle: **Cluedo**

The first stanza was solved before with the work of @NudgeNudge and @Rupert Morrish

> It's a bat - the object as written in hint 5

The second stanza:
In one solid tint i appear, for sure, 
So do my name
I am not Walter
We are not the same

> Mrs. White, she is a solid tint (white), and shares the name with Walter White, the protagonist of Breaking Bad - the character written in hint 5

The third stanza:
At night, I hope,
No need to know Gallileo,
To enjoy the show,
Just look in the scope

> Refers to an Observatory, where you can enjoy the show of the night sky through a telescope - the place written in hint 5

This is all connected by

> The game Cluedo, where you have to name an object, a character and a place where the murder happened. This game has been around since 1949, but a great modernisation happened in 2008, where they introduced the bat as a murder weapon, Diane White as a character and the observatory as a place. This served the purpose of getting younger generations interested in the game.

Very nice puzzle! :)

Comment: yep! this was the intended answer well done :)

Answer (score 7):

I think I've got most of it figured out.

Was the thing that happened in 1974...

> Flying_whale (OP) was born?

A wooden device on which we can read, The cetacean doesn't keep an air of mystery about itself, indeed.

> We are using a computer (or some other device) to look at the riddle and read about flying_whale. When a user neglects to fill out their 'about me' section on SE, the message that appears is 'Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.' However, flying_whale has. Furthermore, cetaceans is used to refer to whales.

In one solid tint i appear, for sure, So do my name.

> In his profile picture, he appears purely black, and his name is also black text.

I am not Walter, we are not the same.

> It's flying_whale, not Walter.

At night, I hope, No need to know Gallileo, To enjoy the show, Just look in the scope

> It's a flying whale. If it's flying, you need to look up into the sky to see it, and because of it's size, you can just look at it.

Comment: I'm sorry but you have guess pretty everything wrong, you should try to connect my infos and the date i gave ;)

Answer (score 5):

Not even a partial answer, just working through the clues.

> Day 228 in non-leap years is 16th of August. 
>  The only interesting thing that seems to have happened on that day in 1974 was the Ramones' debut concert.

Comment: You are one the right tracks, this is Indeed a part of the first stanza

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

1974, something happened on day 228,

> As Rupert Morrish identified, August 16th 1974 was the date of the first Ramones' concert.

An animal is holding, full of hate,
A wooden device on which we can read,

> I guess this could be a guitar? Or maybe a baseball bat, after the Ramones' famous song "[Beat on the Brat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_on_the_Brat)". OP confirms that the *wooden device* line refers to a **bat**, which is the word we're looking for in this stanza?

The cetacean doesn't keep an air of mystery about itself, indeed.

> Flying_whale, the OP, has a bio that states "I'm not from where it appears, but some people used to party here". Their location is 315 Bowery Street, Brooklyn, NY, USA, which is where CBGB's, where Ramones played their first gig, stood.

In one solid tint i appear, for sure, 
So do my name
I am not Walter
We are not the same

> I guess we're looking for a color here. Walter could refer to Walter *White*, and since it's telling us that it isn't that, it could be the opposite color, **black**.

---

Other guesses:

> From the title and the fact that we're looking for a story, I'd say the answer is probably a movie or a TV show that came out in 2008. Most likely a show, according to the third stanza. Could be a coincidence but arguably the two biggest shows to start that year feature a main character named Walter (*Breaking Bad* and *Fringe*).
> Also now that it's confirmed that **bat** is correct, *The Dark Knight* came out in 2008, which could be the right answer.

Comment: what's inside your 3rd spoiler was to connect with the date to find what's inside your first spoiler. What's inside your second spoiler is not correct but is clearly linked to to what you've found so far

Comment: your edit on 2nd spoiler is correct :)

Comment: You found the right word for 1st stanza. for 2nd, rot13(bar bs gur fubjf lbh zragvbarq vf eryngrq gb zl "fgbel", vg'f n pbvapvqrapr gung gur fubjf lbh zragvbarq fgnegrq va 2008 gubhtu)

Comment: rot13(gur qnex xavtug vf abg gur nafjre. gur "ong" lbh sbhaq vf gur bowrpg, abg gur navzny)